# missing tag is meta/worthless

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we really need [missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/missing)? I can't imagine anyone subscribing to it.

Comment: Do we even need to argue about this?

Comment: I thought this is how we wanted to do this? I'd be more than happy to just put them all on one list. :)

Comment: Oh, no - although this is how we're supposed to do it, it's just that this is such a stupid tag that we can destroy it... ;P

Comment: @jrg srry il make a new post

Answer (score 11):

#### Get rid of it

Remove it, it just gets in the way and confuses people.

Comment: Then there would be a meta post about missing the missing tag.

Comment: The missing tag is too broad. Missing Operating System to missing games in Ubuntu Software Center? Remove it.

Answer (score -5):

#### Keep it!

You would suck for removing such an amazing tag!